Proving properties of simple power function in Dafny
The following verifies fine and for obvious reasons.
function power(x: int, y: int) : int
    requires y >= 0
    ensures y == 0 ==> power(x,y) == 1
    ensures y > 0 && y % 2 == 0 ==> power(x,y) == power(x*x,y/2)
    ensures y > 0 && y % 2 == 1 ==> power(x,y) == x * power(x*x,(y-1)/2)
    decreases y
{
    if y == 0 then
        1
    else if y % 2 == 0 then
        power(x*x, y/2)
    else 
        (x * power(x*x,(y-1)/2))
}

I wish to verify the following two properties as well by addding corresponding ensures clauses --
ensures y > 0 ==> power(x, y) == x * power(x, y - 1)
ensures forall a :: 0 <= a <= y ==> power(x, y) == power(x, a) * power(x, y - a)

Adding either one of the above ensures clauses takes dafny verify test.dfy into a seemingly unending loop with CPU pegged at 100%. How do I verify those properties of this function?
Should I add lemmas that prove those properties step by step?

A problem that will often come up is that multiplication is not decidable and frequently it will cause Dafny/Z3 to not verify unless you force it to think symbolically which you can do by making the operations opaque. To verify properties about functions in Dafny induction is the name of the game.
module SO4 {
opaque function prod(x: int, y: int): int {
    x * y
}

lemma ProdAssoc(x: int, y: int, z: int)
    ensures prod(x, prod(y,z)) == prod(prod(x, y), z)
{
    reveal prod();
}

opaque function div(x: int, y: int): int 
    requires y != 0
{
    x / y
}

function power(x: int, y: int) : int
    requires y >= 0
    decreases y
{
    reveal prod();
    reveal div();
    if y == 0 then
        1
    else if y % 2 == 0 then
        power(prod(x,x), div(y,2))
    else 
        prod(x, power(prod(x,x), div(y-1,2)))
}

lemma PowerResults(x: int, y: int) 
    ensures y == 0 ==> power(x,y) == 1
    ensures y > 0 && y % 2 == 0 ==> div(y,2) >=0 && power(x,y) == power(prod(x,x), div(y,2))
    ensures y > 0 && y % 2 == 1 ==> div(y-1,2) >=0 && power(x,y) == prod(x, power(prod(x,x),div(y-1,2)))
{
    reveal div();
    reveal prod();
}
lemma PowerOne(x: int)
    ensures power(x, 1) == x
{
    reveal div();
    reveal prod();
    assert div(0,2) == 0;
    calc {
        power(x, 1);
        {PowerResults(x, 1);}
        prod(x, power(prod(x,x), div(1-1, 2)));
        prod(x, 1);
        x;
    }
}

lemma  PowerCompleteness(x: int, y: int)
    requires y > 0
    ensures power(x, y) == prod(x , power(x, y - 1))
    decreases y
{
    PowerResults(x,y);
    if y == 1 {
        assert div(y-1,2) == 0 by {
            reveal div();
        }
        calc { 
            power(x,y);
            prod(x, power(prod(x,x),div(y-1,2)));
            prod(x,1);
            {reveal prod();}
            x;
            {reveal prod();}
            prod(x , 1);
            prod(x , power(x, y-1));
        }
        

    }else if y == 2 {
        assert div(y,2) == 1 by {
            reveal div();
        }
        assert div(1-1, 2) == 0 by {
            reveal div();
        }
        calc {
            power(x,y);
            power(prod(x,x), 1);
            {PowerResults(prod(x,x), 1);}
            prod(prod(x,x), power(prod(prod(x,x), prod(x,x)), 0));
            prod(prod(x,x),1);
            {reveal prod();}
            prod(x,x);
            {PowerOne(x);}
            prod(x,power(x, y-1));
        }
    }else{
        if y % 2 == 0 {
            assert y-2 > 0;
            assert (y-2)%2 == 0;
            assert 0 < div(y,2) < y by {
                reveal div();
            }
            calc {
                div(y-2,2);
                {reveal div();}
                div(y,2)-1;
            }
            calc {
                prod(x,power(x,y-1));
                {PowerCompleteness(x, y-1);}
                prod(x,prod(x,power(x, y-2)));
                {ProdAssoc(x,x, power(x, y-2));}
                prod(prod(x,x),power(x, y-2));
                {PowerResults(x, y-2);}
                prod(prod(x,x),power(prod(x,x), div(y-2,2)));
                prod(prod(x,x),power(prod(x,x), div(y,2)-1));
                {PowerCompleteness(prod(x,x), div(y,2));}
                power(prod(x,x), div(y,2));
                power(x,y);
            }

        }else{
            assert y >= 3;
            assert div(y-3,2) >=0 by {
                reveal div();
            }
            assert (y-1)%2==0;
            assert (y-2)%2==1;
            calc {
                div(y-1,2) -1;
                {reveal div();}
                div(y-3,2);
            }
            assert 0 < div(y-1,2) < y  by { 
                 reveal div();
            }
            PowerCompleteness(x, y-1);
            PowerCompleteness(prod(x,x), div(y-1,2));
            calc {
                power(x,y);
                prod(x, power(prod(x,x), div(y-1,2)));
                prod(x,prod(prod(x,x),power(prod(x,x), div(y-3,2))));
                prod(x , prod(x , power(x,y-2)));
                prod(x , power(x, y-1));
            }

        }

    }
}

    method Test() {
        assert power(2, 37) == 137438953472 by {
            reveal prod();
            reveal div();
        }
    }

}


This looks like the right approach ... and I didn't know about opaque operations and reveal. Thanks much and will try along these lines. Looks like a similar work out lemma is needed to establish forall a :: 0 <= a <= y ==> prod(power(x,a), power(x,y-a)) == power(x,y).

I think Divyanshu's result should work if you rewrite it in terms of prod and div.

It is possible to verify those properties with additional lemma (See gist). But generally it is advisable that original definition is simple. Complex theorems about definitions can be proved separately as lemma.
Why not use following definition and prove those additional post conditions as lemmas.
 function power(x: int, y: int) : int
    requires y >= 0
    decreases y
{
    if y == 0 then 1
    else x * power(x, y - 1)
}


lemma powerLower(x: int, y : int) 
  requires y >= 0 
  ensures y % 2 == 0 ==> power(x, y) == power(x * x, y / 2)
  ensures y % 2 == 1 ==> power(x, y) == x * power(x * x, (y - 1) /2)
{
   if y == 0 {}
   else {
       if y % 2 == 0 {
          powerLower(x, y - 2);
       }
   } 
}


I started with this but am interested in proving that the lower complexity version is equivalent. Dafny wasn't able to induce those properties from this version too.

I have updated answer to show how to use this version and prove lower complexity version.
